# Why is temp table not getting dropped when executing sql script via jdbc template?

Tags: jdbc, sybase, spring-jdbc

I am trying to execute the sql script shown below via jdbcTemplate.execute(....);

```
if object_id('#dao_bulk_trade') is not null
  exec('drop table #dao_bulk_trade')

create table #dao_bulk_trade(thread varchar(128),contract_id int null,contract_version int null)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb..sysindexes WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('#dao_bulk_trade') AND name='ncidx1')
  exec('drop index #dao_bulk_trade.ncidx1')

create unique nonclustered index ncidx1 on #dao_bulk_trade (thread, contract_id)
```

The first time I call the corresponding DAO endpoint via swagger it executes the SQL script and creates the table.  If I however, I then make the same call again via swagger it blows up with the error below.

```
"Cannot create temporary table '#dao_bulk_trade'. Prefix name '#dao_bulk_trade' is already in use by another temporary table '#dao_bulk_trade'."
```

I have auto commit set to true on my jdbc connections in the Hikari pool.  I am at a loss as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated during the compilation phase when all 4 commands are processed as a single unit of work.

When the temp table exists the 2nd command (`create table`) fails to compile because the object already exists.

*NOTE:* While the `if` tests are considered during the compilation phase the contents of the `exec(...)` calls are skipped over and will be processed at runtime.

To get around this issue you need to insure the `drop table` and `create table` commands are processed in separate command batches; same goes for the `drop index` and `create index` commands.

You have a couple options:

- wrap the `create table` and `create index` commands in `exec(...)` wrappers; this will delay the compilation of these commands until runtime at which point each `exec(...)` is processed as single standalone commands; in this case all 4 commands will be compiled at runtime as if submitted as 4 separate command batches
- break this single, 4-command batch into separate command batches

One idea for the 2nd option (separate command batches):

```
-- 1st batch

if/drop table
go

-- 2nd batch

create table
create index
go
```

**NOTES:**

- the `go` designates the end of a batch when submitted via the `isql` command line tool; I'm not familiar with `jdbc` so not sure what the equivalent would be of the `isql/go`
- I'm guessing someone ran into this same issue with the `drop table/index` commands (eg, 1st time running the batch an error was generated complaining the object couldn't be dropped because it didn't exist); the resolution in that case was the inclusion of the `exec(...)` wrappers; same explanation applies here, and the same resolution applies ... break the compilation phase into chunks ... either literally or via runtime/`exec(...)` wrappers